# webcam feed with opencv and tkinter

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I wrote a program in python using `opencv` and `tkinter` that provides display a video webcam feed and I can do snapshot. I have one button called as snapshot and file name saved as timestamp, but I want to save file name by my own(user) instead of timestamp. I don't have any idea, I am beginner in python and tkinter. Can you please help me?

following is my photoboothapp code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import tkinter as tki
import threading
import datetime
import imutils
import cv2
import os

class PhotoBoothApp:
    def __init__(self, vs, outputPath):
        self.vs = vs
        self.outputPath = outputPath
        self.frame = None
        self.thread = None
        self.stopEvent = None

        # initialize the root window and image panel
        self.root = tki.Tk()
        self.panel = None

        # create a button, that when pressed, will take the current
        # frame and save it to file
                btm = tki.Button(self.root, text="name",command=callback)
        btn = tki.Button(self.root, text="Snapshot!",
            command=self.takeSnapshot)

                #btm = tki.Button(self.root, text="name",command=callback)

                #btm=tki.Button(self.root,text="name",command=callback)
        btn.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10,
            pady=10)
                #btm.pack(side="bottom",fill="both",expand="yes", padx=15,pady=15)
        # start a thread that constantly pools the video sensor for
        # the most recently read frame
        self.stopEvent = threading.Event()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.videoLoop, args=())
        self.thread.start()

        # set a callback to handle when the window is closed
        self.root.wm_title("PyImageSearch PhotoBooth")
        self.root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.onClose)

    def videoLoop(self):
        # DISCLAIMER:
        # I'm not a GUI developer, nor do I even pretend to be. This
        # try/except statement is a pretty ugly hack to get around
        # a RunTime error that Tkinter throws due to threading
        try:
            # keep looping over frames until we are instructed to stop
            while not self.stopEvent.is_set():
                # grab the frame from the video stream and resize it to
                # have a maximum width of 300 pixels
                self.frame = self.vs.read()
                self.frame = imutils.resize(self.frame, width=300)

                # OpenCV represents images in BGR order; however PIL
                # represents images in RGB order, so we need to swap
                # the channels, then convert to PIL and ImageTk format
                image = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                image = Image.fromarray(image)
                image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

                # if the panel is not None, we need to initialize it
                if self.panel is None:
                    self.panel = tki.Label(image=image)
                    self.panel.image = image
                    self.panel.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

                # otherwise, simply update the panel
                else:
                    self.panel.configure(image=image)
                    self.panel.image = image

        except RuntimeError as e:
            print("[INFO] caught a RuntimeError")

    def takeSnapshot(self):
        # grab the current timestamp and use it to construct the
        # output path
        ts = datetime.datetime.now()
        filename = "{}.jpg".format(ts.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))
        p = os.path.sep.join((self.outputPath, filename))

        # save the file
        cv2.imwrite(p, self.frame.copy())
        print("[INFO] saved {}".format(filename))

    def onClose(self):
        # set the stop event, cleanup the camera, and allow the rest of
        # the quit process to continue
        print("[INFO] closing...")
        self.stopEvent.set()
        self.vs.stop()
        self.root.quit()
```

Comment: Check out this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476232/save-file-dialog-in-tkinter). `asksaveasfilename()` will open an dialog box which will do stuff you wanna do and you add a button where ever you want and onclicking that button this function can be called inside your `takeSnapshot()`.

Comment: i try it but i can't solve this problem..i'm beginner in python

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you try that...what was the program that you wrote update it in your post question. Don't worry someone will definitely help you

Comment: my problem is that how add button below of snapshot botton??i don't know how i define botton!!

Comment: In your code this line created a button `btn = tki.Button(self.root, text="Snapshot!", command=self.takeSnapshot)` what it means is its `parent` is `root` the `text` on the button will appear `Snapshot!` and it will call the `takeSnapshot()` when clicked.

Comment: ok...for example bmm = tki.Button(self.root, text="name!",command = 
 )...what is it in blank in command??

Comment: Its not a blank the function's call is in multiple line. That is a single one line.

Comment: when add bmm=tki.Button(self.root,text="text",command=self.takeSnapshot) then text and snapshot will act similar

Comment: Yes it will add a button with the text on the button from `Snapshot!` to `text`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Entry widget of tkinter python.

above the button add this lines.

```
Text=Entry(self.root)
Text.pack()
```

and in takeSnapshot() function do this while writing.

```
p=os.path.sep.join((Text.get(), filename))
```

I have edited your code for better understanding.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import tkinter as tki
import threading
import datetime
import imutils
import cv2
import os

class PhotoBoothApp:
    def __init__(self, vs, outputPath):
        self.vs = vs
        self.outputPath = outputPath
        self.frame = None
        self.thread = None
        self.stopEvent = None

        # initialize the root window and image panel
        self.root = tki.Tk()
        self.panel = None

        # create a button, that when pressed, will take the current
        # frame and save it to file
        btm = tki.Button(self.root, text="name",command=callback)
        Text=Entry(self.root)
        Text.pack()
        btn = tki.Button(self.root, text="Snapshot!",
            command=self.takeSnapshot)

                #btm = tki.Button(self.root, text="name",command=callback)

                #btm=tki.Button(self.root,text="name",command=callback)
        btn.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10,
            pady=10)
                #btm.pack(side="bottom",fill="both",expand="yes", padx=15,pady=15)
        # start a thread that constantly pools the video sensor for
        # the most recently read frame
        self.stopEvent = threading.Event()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.videoLoop, args=())
        self.thread.start()

        # set a callback to handle when the window is closed
        self.root.wm_title("PyImageSearch PhotoBooth")
        self.root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.onClose)

    def videoLoop(self):
        # DISCLAIMER:
        # I'm not a GUI developer, nor do I even pretend to be. This
        # try/except statement is a pretty ugly hack to get around
        # a RunTime error that Tkinter throws due to threading
        try:
            # keep looping over frames until we are instructed to stop
            while not self.stopEvent.is_set():
                # grab the frame from the video stream and resize it to
                # have a maximum width of 300 pixels
                self.frame = self.vs.read()
                self.frame = imutils.resize(self.frame, width=300)

                # OpenCV represents images in BGR order; however PIL
                # represents images in RGB order, so we need to swap
                # the channels, then convert to PIL and ImageTk format
                image = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                image = Image.fromarray(image)
                image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

                # if the panel is not None, we need to initialize it
                if self.panel is None:
                    self.panel = tki.Label(image=image)
                    self.panel.image = image
                    self.panel.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

                # otherwise, simply update the panel
                else:
                    self.panel.configure(image=image)
                    self.panel.image = image

        except RuntimeError as e:
            print("[INFO] caught a RuntimeError")

    def takeSnapshot(self):
        # grab the current timestamp and use it to construct the
        # output path
        ts = datetime.datetime.now()
        filename = "{}.jpg".format(ts.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))
        p = os.path.sep.join((Text.get(), filename))

        # save the file
        cv2.imwrite(p, self.frame.copy())
        print("[INFO] saved {}".format(filename))

    def onClose(self):
        # set the stop event, cleanup the camera, and allow the rest of
        # the quit process to continue
        print("[INFO] closing...")
        self.stopEvent.set()
        self.vs.stop()
        self.root.quit()
```

Comment: thank you for your help,this code not worked,first problem is where i haven't webcam running,,but it worked before,,secondly i got following error when i used name:                                                                             p = os.path.sep.join((self.outputPath, filename))
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined